# Php array with combination of number of days and number of users

Tags: php, arrays

i want to get list of days with respect to number of users. Like, if there is 2 users and based on from and to date, will take number of days to get result array.

i have users array with 2 elements and numbers array with 2 elements. Result array will have 4 elements looks like given below

these are my arrays users can have more elements than days or days can have more elements than users

```
$users =    array:2 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "id" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "id" => "2"
  ]
];
$days =    array:2 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "Date" => "01-06-2020"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "Date" => "02-06-2020"
  ]
];

Result array looks like
$result =  array: 4[
      0 => array:2 [
        "Date" => "01-06-2020"
        "User" => "1"
      ]
      1 => array:2 [
        "Date" => "02-06-2020"
        "User" => "1"
      ]
      2 => array:2 [
        "Date" => "01-06-2020"
        "User" => "2"
      ]
      3 => array:2 [
        "Date" => "02-06-2020"
        "User" => "2"
      ]
    ]
```

How can i get this result using foreach

I tried with this

```
foreach ($users as $key=>$user) {
  foreach($days as $val) {
      $result[$key]['Date'] = $val->Date;
      $result[$key]['User'] = $user->id;
      }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask.

Comment: updated with detailed explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confuse arrays and objects. The data you posted as input data is arrays of arrays, not arrays of objects. So you need to access array elements inside your loops, not object properties as you try to:

```
<?php

$users = [
  [ "id" => "1" ],
  [ "id" => "2" ]
];
$days = [
  [ "Date" => "01-06-2020" ],
  [ "Date" => "02-06-2020" ]
];

$result = [];
foreach($users as $user) {
  foreach ($days as $day) {
    $result[] = [
      "Date" => $day["Date"],
      "User" => $user["id"]
    ];
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

The output obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 01-06-2020
            [User] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 02-06-2020
            [User] => 1
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 01-06-2020
            [User] => 2
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 02-06-2020
            [User] => 2
        )
)
```